# how can I call a script with spaces in a variable in zsh?

Tags: command-line, zsh

this works as expected in bash:

```
> t="ls -l"
> $t #== ls -l
> "$t" #== "ls -l"
ls -l: command not found
```

But in zsh I got this:

```
> t="ls -l"
> $t #== "ls -l"
ls -l: command not found
```

How can I force the shell to parse the variable value again like bash does?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946/how-can-we-run-a-command-stored-in-a-variable)

Comment: @muru, the question you linked is related to `bash`. while it's close enough, it's still different :)

Comment: @rush doesn't matter, the only sane way to run commands is using arrays.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want a variable that expands to more than one argument use an array:

```
var=(ls -l)
$var
```

But to store code, the most obvious storage type is a function:

```
myfunction() ls -l
```

Or:

```
myfunction() ls -l "$@"
```

for that function to take extra arguments to be passed to `ls`.

The fact that `bash` like most other Bourne-like shells splits unquoted variables upon expansion is IMO a bug. See [the kind of problems it leads to](/q/171346). But if you want that behaviour, you can set the `shwordsplit` option. You could also add the `globsubst` option to restore another *bug* found in `bash` and other Bourne-like shells where variable expansion is also subject to globbing (aka pathname expansion). Or do the full shebang with `emulate sh` or `emulate ksh` (but lose a few more zsh features).

Without having to go there, you can also tell `zsh` to explicitly split a variable:

```
var='ls -l'
$=var # split on $IFS like the $var of bash/sh
${(s[ ])var} # split on spaces only regardless of the value of $IFS
```

```
var='*.txt'
echo $~var # do pathname expansion like the $var of bash/sh
```

```
var='ls -ld -- *.txt'
$=~var # do both word splitting and filename generation
```

Comment: I don't consider word splitting it a bug at all, since bash is built on that concept (that's why IFS is there and in that form). But it doesn't matter, I just wanted to understand why zsh makes no difference between quoted and unquoted. Thanks for the thorough explanation!

Comment: Reading your post for a second time I realize you mentioned "$@" which is funny, cause that's there because of word splitting. Without code splitting theres no difference between `$*`, `"$*"`,`$@`, `"$@"`,`$1`, `"$1"`, right? Everything is just one large parameter (but perhaps zsh behaves differently under some circumstances like function calls... not sure...

Comment: @estani, zsh makes a difference between quoted and unquoted. For a scalar variable, the difference is when the variable is empty in which case `$var` expands to no argument at all while `"$var"` expands to one empty argument. For arrays, `"$var"` is like `"${var[*]}"` in ksh/bash (elements joined with the first character of `$IFS`), while `$var` is all the non-empty elements as separate arguments (same as `${var[*]}` after a `set -o noglob; IFS=` in ksh/bash). For all the elements (including empty ones) as separate arguments you still need `"${var[@]}"` like in ksh/bash...

Comment: ... though you can shorten it to `"$var[@]"` or can also use the `@` parameter expansion flag (`"${(@)var}"`).

Comment: `$*`/`"$*"`/`$@`/`"$@"/`$1`` are short forms of `$argv[*]`, `"$argv[*]"`, `$argv[@]`, `"$argv[@]"`, `$argv[1]` so are all different. The main difference with ksh/bash is again that word splitting and globbing are not done on top of that when unquoted (which for arrays makes even less sense).

Answer (score 4):

This item is covered in [zsh faq](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/FAQ/zshfaq03.html).

Long story short. There are a few ways to fix the behavior:

1. Set `setopt shwordsplit`:

> ```
> setopt shwordsplit
> t="ls -l"
> $t
> ```

2. Use `eval` (which better to avoid due to possible security issues):

> ```
> t="ls -l"
> eval $t
> ```

Comment: thanks, I didn't know what to look for (didn't realize the term was word splitting)

Answer (score 1):

If the variable is already defined as a string, you can use

```
${=t}
```

The `=` flag tells zsh to use word splitting while expanding the variable.

Comment: That's already covered in my answer